# WPF/C# doesn't see INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, using

I have the following rather simple code in a file called Person.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;


public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public Person(string name, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

When trying to build the solution, I get the following error message for the file Person.cs: "The type or namespace name INotifyPropertyChanged could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" (as well as similar messages for PropertyChangedEventHandler and PropertyChangedEventArgs) -- EVEN THOUGH the required using directive

```
using System.ComponentModel;
```

is clearly there (second from the bottom among the using directives).

Anyone an idea what's going on? I copied the code from [this tutorial](http://wpf.2000things.com/2013/05/27/828-listview-and-gridview-data-binding-example/) (and then adding the using directives myself).
(And yes, I'm new to this, and it may be something silly.)

Thanks.

Comment: Which .Net Version are you using ?

Comment: Is this assembly included as project reference?

Comment: System.dll probably used by him

Comment: Scoregraphic, yes, that was the problem indeed! Turns out I had accidentally made two Person.cs files, one of which (the correct one) hadn't been added (i.e. didn't compile), while I had NOT added the using directives to the OTHER file with the same name, which did compile... So, pretty silly (very silly) indeed, but still great that you suspected it immediately!

Comment: So Scoreographic's comment can be upgraded to being an answer, which I will then accept. Thanks!

Comment: A note on that tutorial code: there's no use in implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` if it's not being used. You'd typically raise the `PropertyChanged` event from within your properties setters (passing in the name of the property that is being set). Without that, the UI won't know when those property values are changed.

Comment: Thanks Pieter (duidelijk ook uit Nederland).

Comment: Yes I agree, implementing INotifyPropertyChanged isn't required or useful here (unless and until the example is extended).